# Having trouble understanding the logic of this while loop

Tags: javascript, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I'm practicing singly-linked list and I'm having trouble understanding the logic of one section of the provided example code. Here is the entire code:

```
function Node(data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.next = null;
}

function SinglyList() {
    this._length = 0;
    this.head = null;
}

SinglyList.prototype.add = function(value) {
    var node = new Node(value),
        currentNode = this.head;

    // 1st use-case: an empty list
    if (!currentNode) {
        this.head = node;
        this._length++;

        return node;
    }

    // 2nd use-case: a non-empty list
    while (currentNode.next) {
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
    }

    currentNode.next = node;

    this._length++;

    return node;
};

SinglyList.prototype.searchNodeAt = function(position) {
    var currentNode = this.head,
        length = this._length,
        count = 1,
        message = {failure: 'Failure: non-existent node in this list.'};

    // 1st use-case: an invalid position
    if (length === 0 || position < 1 || position > length) {
        throw new Error(message.failure);
    }

    // 2nd use-case: a valid position
    while (count < position) {
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
        count++;
    }

    return currentNode;
};

SinglyList.prototype.remove = function(position) {
    var currentNode = this.head,
        length = this._length,
        count = 0,
        message = {failure: 'Failure: non-existent node in this list.'},
        beforeNodeToDelete = null,
        nodeToDelete = null,
        deletedNode = null;

    // 1st use-case: an invalid position
    if (position < 0 || position > length) {
        throw new Error(message.failure);
    }

    // 2nd use-case: the first node is removed
    if (position === 1) {
        this.head = currentNode.next;
        deletedNode = currentNode;
        currentNode = null;
        this._length--;

        return deletedNode;
    }

    // 3rd use-case: any other node is removed
    while (count < position) {
        beforeNodeToDelete = currentNode;
        nodeToDelete = currentNode.next;
        count++;
    }

    beforeNodeToDelete.next = nodeToDelete.next;
    deletedNode = nodeToDelete;
    nodeToDelete = null;
    this._length--;

    return deletedNode;
};
```

I'm having difficulty understanding the while loop in the last method.

```
while (count < position) {
        beforeNodeToDelete = currentNode;
        nodeToDelete = currentNode.next;
        count++;
}
```

I understand that the intent of this code is to iterate through the list until the desired node is reached. But I don't understand how this code achieves that. It seems like it would keep the same values on each iteration of the loop instead of searching through the tree. Is the value of `currentNode` changing in some way I'm missing? Any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: there's other issues ... valid position to delete is 0 to length , but 1 is the first position you can delete ... what if you pass 0 as the position to the function

Comment: but yes, that code you highlighted will loop until count === position, then always delete the second node - so it is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nvm. I solved it. It seems the code was an error after all. An example of a working solution would be:

```
while(count<position){ 
 currentnode = currentNode.next; 
 beforenodetodelete = currentNode; 
 nodetodelete = currentNode.next;
 count++; 
}
```